# What city is this?

Tags: identify-this, where-on-earth, locate-this

What city is this? It's from a screen background on Google chrome cast.

Update 1: Yes I had previously tried to get a high-resolution image (spent 15 minutes Googling for one). I also searched the author's name and website (see bottom-right of the image).

It seems it has been identified as Tokyo by berend.

[image: Cityscape]

Update 2: And the low resolution image was not actually mine, I found it on the internet after Googling. I would have taken a high resolution image using my iPhone of my TV screen but by the time I wanted to, Google Chrome Cast had cycled to another picture. And I wasn't able to cycle back. The fact that someone else had taken a picture of their TV may mean I wasn't the only one interested in it I think. Thank you for all the comments. I am curious as to what "other information" people would expect in this situation?

Comment: Any possibility of getting a higher-resolution photo?  It's quite hard to make out fine details in this tiny picture.

Comment: Photo indentification requests need much more detail, including what you have already tried.

Comment: This is a view of Tokyo, the white building in the bottom left is the [Lion Corporation Headquarters](https://goo.gl/maps/6NtGBGMjubPAi1mj6). View it here on Google Earth: https://earth.google.com/web/search/tokyo/@35.70477785,139.7968575,7.54293252a,778.03168148d,35y,-107.92856956h,73.80910436t,0r/data=CigiJgokCXPKp5aGDUpAEcvq_hh5C0pAGTrjJe-TfxRAIT9HtXiGZRRA

Comment: If you could please add additional information to the question it can be reopened, so I can post an answer.

Comment: @berend There have been problems with poor quality questions of this type. See [this debate](https://travel.meta.stackexchange.com/q/6629/105640) on Meta. I would vote against reopening this question.

Comment: @Arthur'sPass That discussion contains both pros and cons of these type of question, but I don't see a general consensus yet. One of Willeke's points is *But if someone can identify, a re-open request should also be the norm, so an answer can be posted*. So personally I don't see a particular reason not to reopen this question. Although it would have been nice if OP had shown at least *some* effort ;-)

Comment: I have re-opened but I would like to see the question improved a lot more. A better photo would be great.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because it contains next to no information by which to identify the location.

Comment: Context on my above vote to re-close: the meta discussion showed a range of views on exactly how to handle such vague ‘where is this’ questions, but the one thing that seemed to have a consensus was that questions without a reasonable amount of information aren’t desired or useful and should be closed. The fact somebody was able to answer doesn’t make this question any better. Given that no change has been made to address the reason the question was closed, the question should remain closed. Reopening to let somebody answer only encourages and enables further low quality questions.

Comment: I'll add to @ChrisH's comment that another issue in the meta discussion was the interest or applicability of the identification to anyone other than the OP. In this question, I think the assessment would be "not much, or nothing." This is a low quality question, and should be closed,

Comment: Concerning the matter of what additional information should be included: typically context such as an approximate part of the world, rough date, etc. Anything to make the question significantly less vague than “here is a photo, where was it taken?”. That you may not have such information in this case doesn’t make the question any better, it just means this is the wrong place to ask.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The picture is from Tokyo taken from the [SkyTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Skytree) and looking toward the [Mount Fuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Fuji).

Same perspective from this [Tokyo Skyline & Mount Fuji 4K Wallpaper / Desktop Backgroung](https://www.flickr.com/photos/looksgood/21118530996/) by [Loek Janssen](https://www.flickr.com/photos/looksgood/):

[image]

> 4K Wallpaper / background of the skyline of the city of Tokyo. with [Mount Fuji](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Mount_Fuji) in the background. Photo taken from the [SkyTree](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Skytree):

[image]

([image source](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tokyo_Skytree#/media/File:Tokyo_Skytree_2014_%E2%85%A2.jpg), CC BY-SA 3.0, taken by [Kakidai](https://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/User:Kakidai))

---

I agree with the OP, I have no idea what the commenters above expect for "more information" since the OP simply saw the picture as a background on some computer/TV, unless there is some way to get meaningful filenames, in which case that'd probably directly solve the question and that's a question for SU. There aren't that many large cities in the world anyway.  I'd expect that many  "[road warriors and seasoned travelers](https://travel.stackexchange.com/tour)" who are supposed to be on this Stack Exchange website should be able to recognize it. Not to mention that the picture was taken from the tallest tower in the world, so it's not like it's some arcane location...

Comment: That OP doesn’t have additional information doesn’t make the question any less vague.

Comment: @ChrisH I don't see what's vague. Clear to me.

Comment: The question provides no detail about the location beyond that it is a city. If you don’t see what’s vague about that I have no idea what to tell you.

Comment: @ChrisH This means that the OP has clearly no idea about the location. So the question is clear to me.

Comment: The aim of the question is clear. The information within it is extremely vague. OP not having more doesn’t change that, or make the question any better. There’s a large meta discussion linked in the comments on the question which might make the intended meaning of “vague” clearer..

Comment: @ChrisH I see. Anyway even a consensus was reached, that wouldn't matter since on this website people close vote for whatever reason they want. Travel is supposed to be enjoyable but this isn't reflected in the ambiance of this website.

Comment: @FranckDernoncourt You ask a lot of low-effort questions here, and have been around long enough that you should know how this site works by now.  If you want people to work to find the answers, you need to demonstrate that you've put some effort into the questions.

Comment: @lambshaanxy I disagree, my questions typically aren't low effort. In fact I've received the opposite complain several times: some of my questions should be asked on a more specialized forum. And I don't expect people to work to find answers. Instead I am assuming that in most cases some users may know the answer based in their experience.